# Alterar a posição de uma <li> para a primeira posição

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho a seguinte `<ul>`:

```
  <ul class="opcoes">
     <li id="">Escolha a opção abaixo</li>
     <li id="1">1</li>
     <li id="2">1</li>
     <li id="3">3</li>
  </ul>
```

Tem como **alterar a posição** de uma `<li>` para a **primeira posição** da `<ul>` em jQuery ao clicar sobre a dada `<li>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente

```js
$('li').click(function(){ $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="opcoes">
     <li id="">Escolha a opção abaixo</li>
     <li id="1">1</li>
     <li id="2">1</li>
     <li id="3">3</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: isso mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Criei um exemplo baseado no que entendi sobre o seu questionamento, veja se o código abaixo corresponde a sua necessidade.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let opcoes = $('.opcoes');
  let opcoesItems = opcoes.find('li');
  
  opcoesItems.each(function(i){
   $(this).click(function(e){
     opcoes.prepend($(this));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Selecione uma opção</h2>

<ul class="opcoes">
  <li id="1">1</li>
  <li id="2">1</li>
  <li id="3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Tive que adaptar seu código HTML para que a lógica funcionasse corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

**Esse tem efeito na transição**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').click(function() {
  // the clicked LI
  var clicked = $(this);

  // all the LIs above the clicked one
  var previousAll = clicked.prevAll();

  // only proceed if it's not already on top (no previous siblings)
  if(previousAll.length > 0) {
    // top LI
    var top = $(previousAll[previousAll.length - 1]);

    // immediately previous LI
    var previous = $(previousAll[0]);

    // how far up do we need to move the clicked LI?
    var moveUp = clicked.attr('offsetTop') - top.attr('offsetTop');

    // how far down do we need to move the previous siblings?
    var moveDown = (clicked.offset().top + clicked.outerHeight()) - (previous.offset().top + previous.outerHeight());

    // let's move stuff
    clicked.css('position', 'relative');
    previousAll.css('position', 'relative');
    clicked.animate({'top': -moveUp});
    previousAll.animate({'top': moveDown}, {complete: function() {
      // rearrange the DOM and restore positioning when we're done moving
      clicked.parent().prepend(clicked);
      clicked.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0});
      previousAll.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 0}); 
    }});
  }
});
  });
```

```css
a,a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
ul{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Escolha a opção abaixo</li>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Fonte:  [**brother**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625960/move-list-item-to-top-of-unordered-list-using-jquery)

Comment: Esse com um efeito ... kkk !!! #massa

Answer (score 3):

Forma usando `.prependTo()` e respeitando a hierarquia dos elementos:

```
$('.opcoes li').on("click",function(){ $(this).prependTo($(".opcoes")); });
```

```js
$('.opcoes li').on("click",function(){ $(this).prependTo($(".opcoes")); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="opcoes">
 <li id="">Escolha a opção abaixo</li>
 <li id="1">1</li>
 <li id="2">1</li>
 <li id="3">3</li>
</ul>
```